# Terraform AWS certificate hangs on validation, although records are created (manually confirmed)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following terraform, intended to:

- Create an S3 bucket
- Create a CloudFront distribution, with the bucket as its origin
- Create a Route53 hosted zone
- Create an ACM certificate
- Validate the certificate via DNS
- Add some other DNS records to the hosted zone.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.0.4"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "acm"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "frontend_access" {
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.frontend.arn}/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.frontend_access.iam_arn]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "frontend_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "frontend" {
  bucket = "domain-frontend"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "default" {
  provider = aws.acm
  domain_name = "domain.com"
  subject_alternative_names = ["api.domain.com"]
  validation_method = "DNS"
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
}




resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "certValidation" {
  provider = aws.acm
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.default.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.validation : record.fqdn]
}


resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "domain.com"
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "frontend_domain" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name = "domain.com"
  type = "A"

  alias {
    name = aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution.domain_name
    zone_id = aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}



resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_record" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name = "domain.com"
  type = "MX"
  ttl = 300
  records = [
    "1 aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com."
  ]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "google_site_verification" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name = "domain.com"
  type = "TXT"
  ttl = 300
  records = ["VALUE"]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "dkim" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name = "google._domainkey.domain.com"
  type = "TXT"
  ttl = 300
  records = ["VALUE"]
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.frontend.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = aws_s3_bucket.frontend.id
    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.frontend_access.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = aws_s3_bucket.frontend.id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
      locations = []
    }
  }

  price_class = "PriceClass_100"

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.default.arn
    ssl_support_method = "sni-only"
  }
}
```

The observed behaviour is that the terraform script hangs on `aws_acm_certificate_validation.certValidation Still creating... [time elapsed]` for forty five minutes, at which point it fails with `Error creating CloudFront distribution: InvalidViewerCertificate: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't in the us-east-1 region, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain.` I have manually checked the records on the hosted zone, and the validation CNAME records are present.

Comment: I would try separating out this resource creation. Put the ACM & Route53 Validation in one plan / root module & the rest of it in another. You can add terraform outputs in your 1st root module, that can be accessed via terraform data sources in your 2nd plan / root module that creates the rest of the resources. I don't have time now to show exactly what that looks like, but if you're still stuck, lmk & I can do that.

Comment: I don't think that the records are created properly. Although the CNAME records are present, and look fine to me, even after 24 hours, AWS has not validated the certificate.

Comment: I tried with your example "domain.com" & that didn't work for me either, yet domain.com is owned by someone else so that is why the validation didn't work for me. Can you confirm that the domain name you are trying to validate is actually owned by you & you have access to the registrar account where you can update the Name Servers (NS) to be your Route53 AWS Name Servers?

Comment: Sorry, I swapped out the domain for privacy reasons, it's owned by me, purchased via AWS Route53, so yes, I can update the NS records for the domain.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your error with the same code & with a domain I own. Only if I use a domain that doesn't have the proper name servers in the registrar or that I don't own can I reproduce this error. So the only thing I can say at this point is to verify that the CNAME verification records are being created in the proper Hosted Zone & ensure that your Hosted Zone is public, not private.

Answer (score 2):

1 reason your new ACM Cert will not properly validate via DNS is because of your domain.com registrar Name Server settings. If the registrar (Where you purchased your domain.com) is different from Route53, you have to ensure to update the Name Servers (NS) in your registrar settings to be the Route53 Name Servers in your Hosted Zone otherwise the DNS validation cannot properly complete. I've tested with a domain I own and the above validation works as expected.

I tried reproducing this error & I could not unless I used a domain I didn't own.

Ensure your Hosted Zone is public, not private.
You can also add terraform outputs to help troubleshoot. In this case I added;

```
output "validation" {
  value = [for record in aws_route53_record.validation : record.fqdn]
}
```